How do I use TP-Link parental controls when I am using the router as a WDS bridge?
My ISP provided a router but it does not provide an admin panel with any useful settings other than letting me change the SSID and password.
I bought my own router, a TP-Link TL-WR940N which I wirelessly connected to my ISP routers using the TP-Link's WDS feature.
I've connected my children's device to the TP-Link in the hopes that the Parental Controls on the TP-Link would work on my children's devices. However, they are not working and the children are still able to access all website at all times.
Is there another way to both use WDS bridging AND use the router's parental controls?

Sounds like you're using the TP-Link like a wireless access point. The parental controls are probably part of the firewall, and that requires that you use the device as an actual router (rather than a wireless bridge), i.e. connect the ISP device (in bridged mode) to the WAN port of the TP-Link router).

It has to be physically connected to work, or is there a way to do it wirelessly?

It depends on the firmware. It probably limits what you can configure when bridging via WiFi. Alternative firmwares like OpenWRT typically expose the same settings.
